# Unable to cross compile a C program to be compatible on Windows host from Ubuntu VM

Tags: c, windows-7, cross-compiling, ubuntu-16.04, vmware-workstation

I'm having issues compiling a C program and running it on a Windows 7 64bit machine.

Here's my script:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     bool isCaseSensitive = false;
     enum { CHARACTER_MODE, WORD_MODE, LINE_MODE } mode = CHARACTER_MODE;
     size_t optind;
     for (optind = 1; optind < argc && argv[optind][0] == '-'; optind++)
     {
         switch(argv[optind][1])
         {
             case 'h': isCaseSensitive = true; printf("Help page"); break;

         default:
             fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-h]\n", argv[0]);
             exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Firstly I'm compiling this script using Ubuntu 16.04 over vmware with a Windows 7 host. When I run: `gcc -m64 utilis.c -o utilis.exe` it will compile, but if I run it on my host I get this error:

[image]

If I try to compile it using 32bit, and having one of my buddies run it on his 32bit machine I get the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I have him run the 64bit one he gets this error:

[image]

What I've tried to do about this:

```
e@ubuntu:/mnt/hgfs/devshare/utilis$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 95 not upgraded.

e@ubuntu:/mnt/hgfs/devshare/utilis$ sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc-multilib is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
gcc-multilib set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 95 not upgraded.

e@ubuntu:/mnt/hgfs/devshare/utilis$ export LDFLAGS='-m32 -L/usr/lib32'

e@ubuntu:/mnt/hgfs/devshare/utilis$ export LDFLAGS='-m64 -L/usr/lib64'

e@ubuntu:/mnt/hgfs/devshare/utilis$ sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++-multilib is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 95 not upgraded.
```

How can I get my program to compile correctly and be cross compatible to my Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, you need to install `mingw` toolchain for linux.

```
sudo apt-get install x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
e@ubuntu:/mnt/hgfs/devshare/utilis$ mg++ utilis.c -o utilis.exe --static
C:\Users\z-perkins-thomas\Documents\bin\testenv\devshare\utilis>utilis.exe -h
Help page
```

[Here's](http://swarminglogic.com/article/2014_11_crosscompile) a step by step on cross compiling `C` programs to run them on Windows

Comment: Well that's what I mentioned Cygwin or Mingw or other cross compilation toolchain will do the job. Finally , great .